# Error: "No matching function for call to Date::Date()"

Tags: c++, oop

I tried to implement the constructor for the `Person` class (see code at the end of the post). Codeblocks gives this error for line 37 (i.e. `const Date &date)`):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Date::Date()'
```

Why is  the constructor for `Date` being called? How do I fix the error?

```
class Date
{
    public:
        Date(int day, int month, int year);
        int GetYear() const;
    private:
        int Day;
        int Month;
        int Year;
};

Date::Date(int day, int month, int year){

    Day = day;
    Month = month;
    Year = year;
}

class Person
{
    public:
        Person(const string &name, const string &address, const Date &date);
        string GetAddress() const;
        string GetName() const;
    private:
        string Name;
        string Address;
        Date DateOfBirth;
};

Person::Person(const string &name,
               const string &address,
               const Date &date)
{
    Name = name;
    Address = address;
    DateOfBirth = date;
}
```

Comment: Provide a default constructor for your Date class.

Comment: @sweenish. I tested, that does work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called because members are initialized *before* the constructor body is entered - in your `Person` constructor, you are assigning to the members, not initializing them.
Since you're not explicitly initializing the members, they are default-initialized first.

Use the initializer list for initialization:

```
Person::Person(const string &name,
               const string &address,
               const Date &date)
    : Name(name),
      Address(address),
      DateOfBirth(date)
{
    // Nothing needs to be done here.
}
```